# How can I find a string in a JSON string using a regular expression on PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have string with hyphens:

```
$str = `Res TP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: dlnHlWqQ4h57DuALMOjKJmxbNn8=
Server: workerman/4.1.9

rec{"result":1}len14`
```

How can I extract a substring {"result":1} from this string?

Comment: out of curiosity are you connecting to a websocket with sockets or using any library or was that just a webrequest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have 1 JSON block (and no other {} symbols) in your string

```
$str = 'Res TP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: dlnHlWqQ4h57DuALMOjKJmxbNn8=
Server: workerman/4.1.9

rec{"result":1}len14';

$pattern = '[{(.*)}]';

if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)) {    
    print_r($matches);    
}

print_r(json_decode($matches[0]));
```

Result is

```
> Array
(
    [0] => {"result":1}
    [1] => "result":1
)
```

So $matches[0] contains your JSON data which can be decoded to create an object

```
stdClass Object
(
    [result] => 1
)
```